# Strange case of a lost post

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, search

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180941/visual-studio-2013-interprets-my-file-as-a-form-file/23182459#23182459) yesterday.  Today I discovered that my answer had an unintended side-effect and went back to delete it again.

Color me surprised when I did not see the post in the question, not even as a deleted post.  Even stranger, I can actually find the post back when I search for it.  Not just once, *three times*.  A screen shot from the search results I got:

[image]

Note how the post appears three times.  The URLs for them are:

- [Visual Studio 2013 interprets my file as a form file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180941/visual-studio-2013-interprets-my-file-as-a-form-file/23182459#23182459)
- [Visual Studio 2013 interprets my file as a form file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180941/visual-studio-2013-interprets-my-file-as-a-form-file/23182349#23182349)
- [Visual Studio 2013 interprets my file as a form file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180941/visual-studio-2013-interprets-my-file-as-a-form-file/23182297#23182297)

Something's **very** wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can add the search query to help reproduce this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a17034%20set%20as%20default. By the way, yeah, I can see them on search result, but not on the question...

Comment: The system panicked when it detected that you had entered an answer with a side-effect, and tried to hide the answer under the carpet?

Comment: I'm dying to know... what _"is, frankly, a pita"_!? It's not often bread gets mentioned in the same breath as Visual Studio.

Comment: A Pain In The Ass.

Comment: The post IDs for the first two are not the same. One ends in 459, the other in 349. Also, trying to use the short link (stackoverflow.com/a/ID) for each fails, adding to the fact that these posts do not exist.

Comment: Have you figured anything out?

Comment: I haven't.  Seems five SO users don't know what a bug report looks like so it can't be that important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see this question, but what happened was a consequence of how we handle SQL interactions between SQL Server and Elasticsearch.

Since we perform a READ UNCOMMITTED translation isolation level request to SQL when indexing, we can witness posts not quite finished submitting yet (and indeed, these deadlocked and timed out). We don't want to do a serializable read here due to performance and locking but...we have read-only replicas in New York available due to our use of AlwaysOn Availability Groups for high availability, so we can work around the issue. By preferring to read from the replica, we only get posts that fully committed and we side-steps the inherent downsides of the lockless approach by basically cheating.

TL;DR: This was resolved a long time ago, and you shouldn't see it happen anymore :)

Answer (score 17):

Late answer, but I only yesterday saw this question and decided to do some digging. Now that this question is reopened I'll post my comment as an answer.

Your posts have or had the IDs 23182459, 23182349 and 23182297. Some quick binary searching using the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/$ID/edit` pointed out that there are no posts with an ID between 23182009 and 23182567, or a gap of roughly 560 posts.

All posts made between 2014-04-20 12:32:03 and 2014-04-20 12:51:16 (Zulu time) seem to have disappeared, see also the IDs and dates for the top two posts in [this search query for that date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=336&tab=newest&q=created%3a2014-04-20&pagesize=15) (23182568 has been soft-deleted).

Given the search database contains a copy of all posts, it looks like a botched restore or failover of the main database, where someone tried to restore the posts but gave up after a few attempts.

I hope this gives you some peace of mind!

I cannot find any outage data for that date. Perhaps some employee from Stack Overflow remembers what happened?