# Vote count and badge scores not updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-score

*(It has been a week by now)*

Is there something wrong with my account?

I asked whether anyone encounter the same issue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28979419#28979419) today, [Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha), a moderator, asked me to post this question on Meta instead, hinting at the possibility of a different bug. Quoting his words here:

> @Ian Funny enough, I do see reputation recalcs as late as today in
>   your account, so it must be a different issue.
>
> @Ian I didn't perform any script for you. There's an automated script
>   that runs every 3am for all users and you guys are skipped for some
>   reason.
>   *(Ian's comment: there seem to be [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5865420/pp) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3134251/lafexlos) guys who experience the same issues on chat, so Madara was referring to the two others)*
>
> Sounds like the best way to get your specific issue resolved
>   @Ian In that case, you can also post on meta. The team listens for bug reports on meta. Link to the old question and explain that it's different (and
>   how)

Thus, following his suggestion, I decided to post this issue on Meta.

I recently encountered this issue where my votes and posts count have not been updated for at least 7 days. For example, take a look on my [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, where I am quite active recently:

[image]

It shows that I have 7 upvotes and 3 posts since 22-Feb. But that is certainly not the case, since I already got [more upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572698/python-if-not-statement-with-0-0/35572950#35572950) and [posts more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5666987%20[python]) since [then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618307/how-to-transform-string-into-dict/35618686#35618686):

[image]

And so I read some of the Meta posts regarding this issue:

- [Why does the vote count on my profile's tags not update?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272647/why-does-the-vote-count-on-my-profiles-tags-not-update)
- [Can I haz stinkin' silver tag badge, plz?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253587/can-i-haz-stinkin-silver-tag-badge-plz)
- [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse)

To see if I can know what causes it and what can I do about it. If nothing goes wrong, by right, we should get an update by once per day:

> The badge awarding is normally part of the tag-score calculations, which runs once a day (at 03:00 UTC) - [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)

But this does not seem to be the case for my account in these 7 days.

However, as the answers of those posts are mostly "just wait and see", I then decided to "just wait and see" until things get better over time.

My questions are classic:

1. Why is this so?
2. Is there anything I can do about it?

---

*(Just in case this may help - users with enough reputation, feel free to edit and to add your name to help the debug process, about 20-30 samples I think should be enough)*

Other people who encounter the same problems as me are:

1. [pp_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5865420/pp) - 1521
2. [Lafexlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3134251/lafexlos) - 2411
3. [Dalija Prasnikar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4267244/dalija-prasnikar) - 8482
4. [Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) - 3465
5. [Everton Lenger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988446/everton-lenger) - 1028
6. [Jayson Minard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3679676/jayson-minard) - 4897
7. [Fabio Lamanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699288/fabio-lamanna) - 2361
8. [Mike Wise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3458744/mike-wise) - 4803
9. [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4927616/matthew) - 2915
10. [Ashish Ahuja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735775/ashish-ahuja) - 1319 (at 2016-02-29 07:00 UTC)
11. [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) - 3911 (at 2016-02-29 07:03 UTC)
12. [Yusuf K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517134/yusuf-kartal) - 2273 (at 2016-02-29 07:49 UTC)
13. [René Vogt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5528593/ren%c3%a9-vogt)  - 4422 (at 2016-04-01 8:15 UTC)

Coincidentally(?), we are all users with rep 1k < rep < 10k

*(rep written by me is as per 29-Feb-2016 3:00 UTC. If you add your name in the list, please write also the time you check your rep)*

Comment: I don't see your post is bringing anything new to the table on this issue, but that's one opinion and one CV.. I am often not in accord with meta, so it doesn't mean your question will be closed.

Comment: @MsYvette hi, please check my post. I have explained why is it different. In the [chat today](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28979408#28979408) a moderator suggests me that this could be a different issue.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the difference is that the problem is not solved by running of nightly script (hence this is a several days problem), seems like different bug and answer can not be applied.

Comment: @PetterFriberg running the nightly scripts does not solve the problem in all the other questions, it's the same question being asked.

Comment: From what I've seen, it is not unusual for these scripts to fail on bad data in the dbase and not complete the job.  Something [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251626/strange-case-of-a-lost-post) for example.  It can take a while for SE employees to do something about it and hand-edit the borken dbase record.  6 to 8 days is the rough expectation..

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the reply. if there is nothing I can do, then I will wait until then.

Comment: @HansPassant strange thing is, if I use Android stack-exchange app, I got a different result. Still incorrect, but certainly different from what I got in the web.

Comment: Well, calculations are currently broken for my account, too.

Comment: Broken for me to and as I can see for all who active in [google-bigquery] tag

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant since when did you experience that? "all who active in" Are you implying that the issue seems to be tag-dependent?

Comment: I was thinking about asking a question in Meta too. Calculations are incorrect in my account as well, in tags [css] and [html].

Comment: @EvertonLenger same question, when did it start?

Comment: i am checking http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-bigquery/topusers on daily basis and what I see is that since approximatelly last Sun/Monday (Feb 21/22) the total score and answers count in chart is literaly frozen for whole tag chart. Reputations though look good.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant that matches with my time... At that time I remember there was a little time for kind of "site maintenance(?)" - you cannot browse SO for about 10 mins, I think.

Comment: @Ian I noticed it last Tuesday.

Comment: @Ian I have the same issue, for Tag kotlin there has been no change in scores for people this entire week, although the activity should be causing scores to go up, they are not.

Comment: Something is surely broken, none on his tag have updated since at least Monday

Comment: @JaysonMinard no, there isn't any update from my side. =(

Comment: do we know if this is going to be fixed? is anyone on this?

Comment: Counts broken here as well.

Comment: Mine have not updated for quite awhile now - maybe 4-5 days.

Comment: It looks like my counts are not updating either (at least in tag gnuplot).  I haven't paid much attention to how long it has been, but I am sure it has been at least 2 days.  It probably has been longer.

Comment: Have we had eyes from a moderator or support that can look into this, it has been silent from those "in the know"

Comment: My C tag has also not been updated for more than a week. I have nearly 69 C answers, and still it is showing 48. I have some 30-35 score on the C tag, but it is still showing my old score of 17.

Comment: A few tweets trying to get someone to notice:  https://twitter.com/JaysonMinard/status/704300494584475648 
https://twitter.com/JaysonMinard/status/704300275230707712

Comment: Looks like my numbers updated today!

Comment: @Matthew - do your numbers look updated today also?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant today the issue seems to be coming again...

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Nope.  They are off again.

Comment: Wow! and again!

Comment: Tag counts off again also on my side, and badge awards as well broken in the main page.

Comment: It seems my issue is a little different. Though my tag score is updated every night, it's only the score displayed at the tag badge progress bar that did not change for several days now. It currently shows 276 for c# while in the tags section the correct number of 345 is shown.

Comment: @RenéVogt I see... there seems to be a related issue to that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317758/tag-badges-are-not-updated-anymore?rq=1 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272647/why-does-the-vote-count-on-my-profiles-tags-not-update?lq=1 we know sometimes the automatic script just doesn't work, though we are of exactly sure yet *why* is it so... well...

Comment: @Ian yes maybe related, but just to be clear: these values are updated _correctly_ in my profile, only the _badge progress bar_ stays at the old value. Good to know someone takes care, thx.

Comment: Update: the progress bar finally updated again and is now only one day behind the value displayed at the tag itself.

Comment: I have this problem also. Badge scores are not updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here was competing and locking jobs being mean to each other at the same time each night. I sent the children to separate rooms a while back but forgot to update this question.

Answer (score 18):

The query has been timing out on Stack Overflow for the last few days.

I have run it manually and increased the current timeout value, so is should complete the next times it is run.

Comment: Thanks, Oded.  When that job terminates, is there a status and timestamp available?

Comment: @HansUp - not that I am aware of. Internally, we know it has run if we don't see an exception in the logs. We will be discussing this on our next team meeting though.

Comment: Thanks again.  The tag topusers pages include *"Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)"*.  I think we could reduce confusion by changing that to *"(last updated: <time stamp>)"* ... if that is practical.

Comment: Thanks for the fix; however, although my tag count on Swift has reached 100 afterward, I have yet been granted with the bronze batch for it. Would I need to wait, still, a bit longer for it?

Comment: @Unheilig - I assume you mean bronze badge? Badge awards run on a different schedule, so that should still come in - possibly in a day or two.

Comment: I saw one time change yesterday. Meantime: a) dont think whole missed week changes were involved; b) tonight it is again not processed

Comment: @Oded But my experience in the past seems to contradict your claim - badge award has always been real-time for me. In addition, tag count update appears to have stopped again since your last manual one.

Comment: Badge awards are not real-time. They are scheduled, though different badges are scheduled at different frequencies (some job run every 5 minutes, some hourly, some daily).

Comment: @Oded, recently when you ran it manually, my score for the `c` tag changed, but again for a day, it has not changed even though I had got many upvotes yesterday.

Comment: @Oded - any update on state of issue? is there any reference on logic on how tag score is calculated? when it was executed daily - at least there was a visibility in this, now when we have week(s) of outage i feel that score is miscalculated or skipping some points, etc. so would be great to know logic of score calculation

Comment: Badge awards are still broken. The score for the sql-server tag  has updated at the beginning of this week, but I still do not have the bronze award.

Comment: There seem to be other problems with the tag score job - I am still investigating and working on a fix.

Comment: @Oded I think there is a related [bug report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318043/tag-badge-not-awarded#comment317051_318043).

Comment: This was fixed, but appears to have returned.

Comment: Scores on topusers page are broken again or I would say still broken

Comment: I can confirm the problem is still present - see [my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321981/2032064)

Answer (score 12):

This has been an issue for several weeks now. It's easy to lose track of the actual vote count. Here's an auditing tool to keep up-to-date:

http://output.jsbin.com/azeqec/12

Just enter your USER ID.

(I discovered this tool a while back on this site and saved it. But I didn't save the post and thus can't provide proper credit. A search with the URL came up empty.)

Comment: This seems to be a good tool for checking our actual vote count indeed.. Not sure if we can allow every user to have such tool in SO to update their vote counts when the autoscript is broken though. ;) It this is feasible, I would love to have.

Comment: @Ian: Just posted as an auditing tool. Not meaning to suggest account integration.

Comment: Ah, yes. It is good. I didn't mean bad, actually. The upvote in your answer was from me. ;) Just wishing that we could have something like that in SO, used by the user.

Comment: It appears [Awesome Poodles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/148310/awesome-poodles) is the source of the script: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179402/192768

Comment: Don't know if this tool works correctly, it shows a c# score for me of 313 while my account states 276. Don't think I gained 37 in only two days, would be nice if these weren't lost.

Comment: @RenéVogt, I just ran my userID through the tool. All numbers are perfectly accurate. The tool provides real-time data. The SO profile page scores update on a schedule, and lag behind the tool. Btw, you've gained a lot of rep in recent days. It may actually add up for you.