# Tag badges are not updated anymore

Tags: support, tag-badges, tag-score

**Before you close this as a duplicate, it is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy).**

I just realized that the tag badge scores are not updated anymore at all. I realized this because my C# tag is nearly on bronze status, I am on score 97. Yesterday, I got an upvote for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502360/219187), which should increment my C# tag score if I'm not mistaken. But my score is still on 97 **on both the activity page and the next tag badge selection**.

I had the same situation with an upvote on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463876/219187) from ~ 1 week ago which should have incremented my architecture tag badge score, but it didn't.

Either I'm misunderstanding the tag badge scoring system, or there is a bug. Is there anyway I can look up which votes affected the tag badge score? Or is there another way how I could verify this "issue"?

Comment: Well, no worries there, we can't close questions as duplicates of those on a different site. But no guarantees someone won't find a duplicate here on Meta SO. :-)

Comment: Probably caching. I'm pretty sure this has been reported before, seems to be a long-standing bug / issue. Might take a while until it's updated. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317757/my-votes-and-posts-count-have-not-been-updated-is-there-something-wrong-with-my, you're not alone.

Comment: Likewise, mine has not been updated since approximately 4 ~ 5 days ago.

Comment: Ok, seems to be a known problem. I guess nobody will post a solution then :-) . But good to know.

Comment: The job that updates the tag badges sometimes dies for a few days. Probably just happened again. Hang tight and I'm sure the team will find it and sort it out.

Comment: I also noticed it hadn't updated for a few days.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It seems like all the StackExchange websites aren't running their daily cron jobs anymore, even the weekly StackOverflow newsletter wasn't send, and all other site weekly newsletter are failing to send too ([bug report on meta for newsletters here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276218/215067))