# Tag badge not awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges, badge-progress

From more than 3 days, I look at my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4363634/chalasr?tab=profile) and I saw that I have a score of more than 100 on the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag.

I expected to see the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) bronze badge awarded.

[image: Profile's badges]

As you can see, the score is ok but not the badge, and my total of badges has not been incremented. The badge has not been awarded.

If I try to change which badge I want to track, all is as if the badge has already been awarded.

[image: Earned badges]

Same for the only trackable [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) which is silver.

[image: Trackable PHP badge]

I tried to logout, track another badge, clear the browser cache ... Nothing happens.

How it's possible ?

**EDIT**

The possible duplicate is about non correctly updated scores.
It's not my problem. My scores are up-to-date.

In fact, the bronze [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) badge should be awarded, the badge tracker view is as if the badge is already awarded, but no congratulations banner, and no badge given.

It seems that SO just forgotten to award me the badge.

Comment: *How it's possible?* [Timing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253638/badge-apparently-awarded-but-not-showing). *From more than 3 days*; I agree, that seems a little extreme.

Comment: I thought [this had been fixed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317757/votes-and-posts-count-for-many-people-have-not-been-updated).

Comment: Same for me for the Matlab bronze badge. Could this "delay" be related with the delay in The updating of the Tag scorse of some days ago?

Comment: @il_raffa It may effectively be a side effect. It took a long week for my score on tag badges was updated. 
It seems we have been skipped.

Comment: @CodyGray the problem [comes back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317757/votes-and-posts-count-for-many-people-have-not-been-updated#comment315510_317921).

Comment: Same with me. Didn't get silver "Android" badge.

Comment: I have a similar problem for a bronze sql-server tag I recently achieved.

Comment: I think tag counts are being updated,, however, badges still do not seem to be awarded.

Comment: This bug has not been fixed.

Comment: Same problem here with the bronze python badge.

Comment: I haven't gotten the struct bronze badge either, even though my score is 100.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the badge awarding is in the same script and the score update,

Comment: @rene My scores haven't been updated during more than a week. When they have been updated, my score on the php tag just reached the bronze, but it was not awarded. Since, nothing happens.

Comment: Glad to see my php bronze badge awarded this morning, in the same time of scores update !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the problem of not awarding tag-badges was fixed when [Oded increased the time-out of the tag-score script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317921/).

Note that the tag-score script is not the same script that awards tag-badges though, they are 'different things' (confirmed by Oded in chat).

Finally, remember that for bronze, silver and gold tag-badges one *also* needs respectively 20, 80 and 200 non-community wiki answers!