# The tag scores have stopped updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-score, top-users

Usually the tag scores update daily at 03:00 UTC. However, I have noticed that for about two weeks now the tag scores have stopped incrementing altogether. For the first few days I assumed that it was a temporary issue that would be picked up and resolved the next time the tag score job successfully completed a run, but despite waiting for several days, the problem has persisted, suggesting there may be a problem with the running of the scheduled tag-score script.

The tags on my home page have looked like this since around 14th December ([archive on 2023-12-15](https://web.archive.org/web/20231215162321/https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron) and [archive on 2023-12-28](https://web.archive.org/web/20231228152205/https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron?tab=profile), both showing 5,527 of my answers in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)):

[image]

Whereas if I [search my answers by user ID and the r tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a12500315%20%5br%5d%20is%3aa%20deleted%3ano&searchOn=3) I find 5,562 results, which is 35 answers more than are included in the tag totals shown in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron?tab=profile) and is the number of new answers I've posted since 14 December. Neither the answers, nor the upvotes / downvotes seem to have been incorporated into the tag totals since that time.

[image]

If tag scores aren't updated, other functionality of the site such as "top users" pages and tag badges will not update either. From looking at the "top users" pages for various tags over this period, this seems to be affecting other (?all) users. I was a bit surprised that it hadn't been raised already on meta.

The same problem appears to have cropped up from time to time in the [distant past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317757/vote-count-and-badge-scores-not-updating), and according to the accepted answer, on that occasion it appears to have been a bug caused by

> competing and locking jobs being mean to each other at the same time

A similar issue was reported [10 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run) with several (maybe all) users being affected at that point. On that occasion, the accepted cause was:

> One of our daily scheduled jobs was timing out, causing tag scores to not refresh.
> We changed the way we were calling the job that was timing out, so this issue shouldn't recur.

A delay of 2 or 3 days seems to be something that can be expected from time to time due to sporadic failure of the scheduled job. However, it does seem that, on both the previous occasions I could find where there was a very long delay in tags being updated, it was due to a recurrent, systematic problem that required some dev intervention.

I thought I would raise it here in case the devs need to have a look.

---

**Update 2024-01-04**

The tags are still not updating a week after originally posting this question. It feels like this is an important feature we are missing from the site. I appreciate that it might take time to fix, but it would be good to hear any feedback from the SE team on this.

---

**Update 2024-01-15**

We now seem to be at a month with no updates on the tag scores. This has several knock-on effects on other features on the site, as mentioned in the comments. It would be great to hear any updates on this.

Comment: I noticed this too. Can verify in SEDE as well (and yes, I made sure to exclude community wiki posts). https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1812351/2201250 (of course, SEDE refreshes on sundays, but that just makes this more obvious: SEDE sees _more_ than what profile page shows- not less). I recently earned a gold tag badge and was wondering if it had anything to do with that, but I guess not.

Comment: Thanks @starball - that's useful. I _thought_ everyone (or at least many folks) were affected, but I couldn't figure out why no-one had raised this already.

Comment: yeah, I also half-noticed a week-ish ago, and shrugged it off initially as me just being wrong, but suspicion slowly grew. Even after my SEDE query, I still doubted myself. I guess I've gotten quite used to bugs typically already having been reported years ago. Also tried searching for a pre-existing MSO post and couldn't find one until Henry Ecker [pointed me here in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56971758#56971758).

Comment: @rene My money is on it being fired

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike I pondered on that joke but considered it to be too dark. You may have it.

Comment: The Top Users statistics page on StackOverflow for the openai-api tag seems to have frozen since the new year too. I know I've provided multiple answers and gotten some reputation, but the numbers seem to be the same for the past 2 weeks.

Comment: @RokBenko yes it's the same root cause, of tag scores not updating, it affects many things, including your case of top users.

Comment: things just keep slowly breaking. I'm partially not surprised with the company struggling/failing to deliver on the target deadlines they set for themselves with their OverflowAI project. see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383520/997587.

Comment: The `scikit-learn` top users haven't been updated since **October**.

Comment: Ah, so I'm not alone. Just took me a while to follow the trail of tag score related questions throughout the years to get to the right search terms to land here. Yes, it's been several weeks now without updated scores on the profile page.

Comment: the scores for tags aren't updating at all, very disturbing

Comment: This will not update your score, but it will show you current tag score, choose your country and the tag then click Run query.

Comment: So by the time the refresh is started it should complete by Christmas [not sure what year]

Comment: I recently took a survey on StackOverflow, and I can tell from the questions asked that ChatGPT is taking away (some?) traffic. This is surely not helping change the trend. @AllanCameron I don't think you're unreasonable.

Comment: Long time coming but somethings updated at last.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We're on this now, it's essentially a truly diabolical query with a penchant for failing silently. Once sorted we can hopefully also put something meaningful in which will flag up this and other similar things more quickly in future.

**UPDATE**: we should now have had a successful run, if everyone could give their profiles a check that'd be grand! Got a few more tweaks to make in this area but hopefully this first step has done the trick. Apologies for how long this took by the way - backlog ownership type stuff around here has become a touch harder recently!

Comment: welcome to MSO! hope to see you around more :)

Comment: Thanks for working to fix this and for providing an update that it's being addressed!

Comment: Yay! Thank you cart! The update is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @cart. Everything works in my case now (i.e., the Top Users statistics page on StackOverflow for the openai-api tag).

Comment: My tag scores got automatically updated about just now.

Comment: "a truly diabolical query with a penchant for failing silently" That is the sort of attitude about programming that produces programs like that.

Comment: My scores updated yesterday (thank you) but did not update overnight. I'm not sure if the update schedule has changed though and this is expected.

Comment: Thank you again cart. I can confirm that the scores updated following the run. Hopefully it can be automated again without a lot of work. Feel free to change the tag on my question to status-completed

Comment: Yeah can confirm another timed out auto run overnight - we think we have a fix that'll bring the running time within reasonable bounds, I'm gonna leave it status-review until we have a consistently successful job!

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to manually cause a tag score update, as long as you don't already have a gold badge in the tag. Simply go to your [Activity Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=summary) page and click on the settings icon next to "Next Tag Badge"

[image]

Pick a tag that you don't have a gold badge on and within around 10 minutes the tag score generally gets updated. This will then reflect back on your [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=tags) page.

Note that this appears to mainly only affect your profile page. On the one tag where I am in the Top Users this had no effect on the scores in the "Last 30 Days" column although it did update my scores in the "All Time" column.

Comment: is this just for the profile page? or does it also update top users on tag pages?

Comment: @starball I just checked and it doesn't appear to have affected the top users for one of the tags that I tried with it.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This is useful, but most of the functionality we want from the tag scores is still disabled. I guess the site could do without tag scores, but it's something that drives engagement from the folks that create content. I'm a bit disappointed that there has been no acknowledgement from SE. Even a comment acknowledging the problem and saying it's a low priority would be fine. At the moment, I have no way of knowing if SE are even aware of it.

Comment: @AllanCameron yes, it wasn't intended as a solution, just a limited workaround. It is appalling that no-one from SE has responded to this. I wonder if you need to post on [meta.se] instead.

Comment: @Nick It was already asked there, but the question was possibly closed and deleted since it might not be happening on other sites. Posting there isn't going to get it fixed faster.

Comment: @Laurel I didn't know that it had already been asked there. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I was looking for an actual bug reporting tool, but everything I have read said says to post bug reports here. I keep thinking I must be missing something or overestimating the importance of tags, since I would have thought a billion-dollar software company would respond  more quickly to a report that a major feature of their flagship product has stopped working. That's over 3 weeks now, and nothing. Maybe I'm being completely unreasonable, but then why all the upvotes on the question? I'm genuinely a bit confused.

Comment: @AllanCameron 20% of staff has been recently laid off, and AI is getting pushed super hard so It's not the surprising to see this taking some time.  It also wouldn't surprise me that there is no one left at the company that knows the code that is responsible for this update.  From what I recall some of this stuff was maintained by just one person.

Answer (score 9):

Guys I got this answer from Staff:

> *I'll keep this ticket open until the issue is resolved and let you know then.
> Thanks,
> ~
> Eric C - Stack Exchange Community Support Team*

So has anything moved forward in this matter? You write that the counter has not been updated for a month, but in my opinion this problem existed even more than a month ago...

**Update 26/01/2024**

Someone may be interested in this, my `tag` counter has been updated and it seems to be working normally.

Comment: what does it even mean to have an _opinion_ on when a bug started?

Comment: What I meant was the fact that I noticed the error of not updating the counter more than a month ago... Generally, it is not important when the error occurred, but when it is fixed...

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. Was this via the support page?

Comment: Yes, I used SE contact form