# Tag vote count seems to be broken for one specific tag

Tags: bug, vote-count

I have been noticing for the past few weeks, my tag score count for [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq) seems to be stuck at 1199 for a while now. Is there by any chance, the daily tag counter broken for my profile?

Even yesterday I got a vote-up for one of the answers in the tag and it still appears to be at the same score. I haven't noticed it for other tags as I don't have a strong recollection of their previous values. This particular tag caught my eye because it has been on the same value (1199) for a while now.

Comment: Probably the same issue as in [The tag scores have stopped updating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427624/the-tag-scores-have-stopped-updating)